# Use a GameCube Controller with Dolphin Emulator 14.04

Tags: 14.04, emulation

I have a Mayflash GameCube controller adapter for my Wii U. I bought it specifically so I could use it on PC as well (it has a separate pc setting on the adapter so I can switch between the two platforms). A friend of mine suggested it because it works with the same emulator, but we were running Windows 10. How do I get a GameCube adapter to work with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this guide: https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=How_to_use_the_Official_GameCube_Controller_Adapter_for_Wii_U_in_Dolphin

The Linux specific instructions can be found here: https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=How_to_use_the_Official_GameCube_Controller_Adapter_for_Wii_U_in_Dolphin#Linux

Also note that the adapter will need to be set to Wii U mode beforehand even if you are using it on a PC.

Comment: are you sure? I bought this specifically so it had the pc mode. It's a Mayflash and it's never worked on pc unless it's in pc mode.

Comment: The udev rule must be created before it will work. The reason you want to have it in Wii U mode is that it will be properly calibrated automatically and will have less input lag. You can read more about Dolphin's Wii U adapter support here: https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2015/01/01/dolphin-progress-report-december-2014/#40-4594-native-support-for-the-official-nintendo-gc-controller-adapter-for-wii-u-by-skidau